# Drupal - Understanding how to print variables

Tags: php, drupal

So when creating a Drupal site (for example) it's a very common development helper to print the variables of a form etc. at the top of the page, e.g. using `dpm()` (assuming the devel module is installed).

I'm having trouble grokking all the ways to do this, and the contexts in which they can be used.

For example, I can use `dpm($form)` within an implementation of hook_form_alter in my custom module. No problem, the variables are printed nicely at the top of the page.

Now, if I look at a template, say, node.tpl.php I see that there are a load of available variables used to construct the page. So if I pick one, e.g. $links, I would've thought that adding `<?php dpm($links); ?>` to node.tpl.php would print the variables out for me. But no!

Why is this, what am I doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dpm()` uses `drupal_set_message()`. At some point in the page rendering process Drupal prints all messages that have been set with this function.
You're using `dpm()` after that point thus it's too late to add messages to this very page. However you should see them on the next page or after refreshing the current. Not helpful for debugging though.

You may want to give the [Theme Developer Module](http://drupal.org/node/209561) a try.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a new variable to an existing template, to see the changes, you must first flush Drupal cache.
[Take a look here to know how to flush Drupal cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230261/how-do-i-empty-drupal-cache-without-devel)

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($row);    
echo "</pre>"; 
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

dpm() put the debug content to session, will be not displayed if that content is too big.

Try `die(kpr($vars));`

Comment: what is kpr? Is it some function?

Comment: a function inside devel.module

Comment: That kills the script before rendering anything.

Answer (score 0):

Display all node variables:

```
<ol>
    {% for key, value in node  %}
        <li>{{ key }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most feasible option is

```
dump($variables);
```

Other options are

```
var_dump($variables); - but it will give a memory error sometime.
print_r($variables); - but it will give a memory error sometime.
dpm($variables); - Sometimes does not work on the front end.
```

[image]